# Invoke action from child component in react

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I have a context provider action

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import MemberSelectionContext from './MemberSelectionContext';

class MemberSelectionProvider extends Component {
    state = {
        selectedMembers: []
    };

    get actions() {
        return {
            onPageChanged: this.onPageChanged
        };
    }

    onPageChanged = data => {

    };

    render() {
        const {children} = this.props;

        return (
            <MemberSelectionContext.Provider value={{
                store: this.state,
                actions: this.actions
            }}>
                {children}
            </MemberSelectionContext.Provider>
        );
    }
}

export default MemberSelectionProvider;
```

`onPageChanged` ```action call from child1`` by the following way

```
<button className="btn btn-outline-secondary" onClick={this.props.actions.onPageChanged}>
                            <i className="fa fa-backward" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;
                            <span className="sr-only-xs">Previous</span>
                        </button>
```

I want to invoke this `onPageChanged` event from another child component which is child2

```
this.props.actions.onPageChanged = function(){

};
```

How can I invoke onPageChanged action from child2?

Answer (score 1):

Just pass a reference of `getActions` to the child as a `prop`

```
class MemberSelectionProvider extends Component {
   get actions() {
        return {
            onPageChanged: this.onPageChanged
        };
   }
   onPageChanged = data => {

   };

   render(){
       return <Child getActions={this.getActions}/>
   }
```

And inside `Child`

```
 const Child = ({ getActions }) =>{
     const actions = getActions()
     acions.onPageChanged()
 }
```

It works for `Providers` as well, but instead of `props` store a reference of `getActions` inside `value` and  consume it like this

```
const context = useContext(MemberSelectionContext)

const actions = context.getActions()
actions.onPageChange()
```

Comment: Where do you call `this.props.actions.onClickPreviousPage`?  This function isn't declared anywhere. Besides that, `actions` isn't a `prop`. How are you consuming your context?

Comment: Sorry, I have changed the questions again. It will ```onClick={this.props.actions.onPageChanged}```

Comment: You are providing `actions` through `context` and calling as a `prop`. `this.props.actions` works inside `ChildA`?

Comment: Yes, It is working, please see the image https://ibb.co/18CKSS1